# Rails Application: Make JQuery functions work in files that are loaded afterwards

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I have quite a problem that I can't solve by myself. I have a Rails application that uses a file "application.html.erb" with a menu controlling the app. Below that menu, in the same file there is a container:

The whole controls are specified in a Javascript / Coffee file that loads data into the previously mentioned container, e.g.
`$('#appCanvas').html "Example text"`

Now I am using Twitter Bootstrap and I include Popovers for some things. I load them via
    $(document).ready ->
      $("#example").popover()

When I specify a link to hover this popover, I use
`<a href="#" title="Show Information" id="example" data-trigger="hover" class="btn btn-danger iconButton"><i class="icon-home"></i></a>`

Those work fine on those links created directly in the application.html.erb file but I just don't find a way to use these popover effects in those parts that are loaded into the appCanvas-Container.

It'd greatly appreciate any help :-)

Thank you and have a great day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what you're saying is things that are not loaded in the `application.html.erb` are not following the `$("#example").popover()`?

Your problem I think lies in the `$(document).ready` part.

`$(document).ready` is basically saying once the page is loaded, follow this JavaScript. It does not pertain to things that are updated once the page has already been loaded.

So what you probably want to do something like this...

**EDIT**

```
$(document).on "mouseover", ->
  $("#example").popover()
```

Comment: Hmm that does not make it work. Any other suggestions? Btw. I think there should be a '=' before the '->', but that didn't change anything, either...